# Joining to Test Domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I keep getting this error when trying to join a test workstation to a test domain. Any idea what this means? Google hasn't been very forthcoming.

> The following error occurred attempting to join the domain "test.companyname.com"
>
> Name Translation: Unable to resolve completely, only the domain was found

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a DNS issue in resolving the actual domain controller. Is the DNS role installed on the test Active Directory Domain Controller(s) in your test environment? Are both the test workstation and the ADDC/DNS server using that ADDC/DNS server as its DNS server (itself, in the case of the ADDC)?

If you're actually using "test.companyname.com" as the domain, and you have not done the above, then you're going to get yourself into a ton of DNS delegation problems. It's probably trying to find the ADDC in companyname.com and only finding that the record exists, but that there's no AD there. This is why you don't use top-level domains in Active Directory. Here are Microsoft's [best practices](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264) concerning naming domains.

Comment: Correct. I have the workstation pointing to the IP of the test DC/Exchange box server (which is a VM running Windows server 2008 R2 x64). The workstation is a laptop running XP pro. I have the dc pointing to itself for DNS.

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference, but I renamed the domain name from "test.companyname.com" to "test.companyname"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it has something to do with DNS (sorry if that is extremely obvious!)

Is DNS running and properly configured on the test domain?

What is the client OS and domain functionality level?

Are these running in a virtual environment or are they two physical machines?

I guess in summation, a lot more info about what you have tried and what your environment would be helpful.

Comment: Test domain controller/exchange 2007 box is a VM running Server 2008 R2 x64 Enterprise. Workstation is a laptop running Windows XP Pro. DNS is running, though I didn't make any special config changes beyond the defualt settings. Domain functionality is 2008 R2.

Comment: The domain is test.companyname, DC name is gnu.test.companyname.com

Comment: On the laptop, I've changed the DNS setting in the IP properties to the IP of the test DC.

Comment: domain name used to be called test.companyname.com but I changed it to test.companyname... not my idea ;o)